navigator.share not working in android(wirking in vivo and samsung devices) working fine on ios devices
While sharing only image description is not coming, and when i share the URL to the image description is working. I want Image + description. I tried using blob too but there was no effect. On sharing the image as canvas also rendered same issue.
<?php
    // Image URL
    $imageUrl = "https://www.example.com/demo/vd/image.jpg";
    $description = "This is an amazing image. Let me share it with you!";
    ?>
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Share Image and Copy Description</title>
    <style>
    .share-btn {
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #007bff;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <h1>Share this Image with Description!</h1>
    <img src="<?php echo $imageUrl; ?>" alt="Awesome Image" width="300" style="border-radius: 8px;">
    
    <!-- Share Button -->
    <button class="share-btn" id="shareBtn">Share Image and Copy Description</button>
    
    <script>

    async function shareImageAsCanvasAndCopyDescription(imageUrl, description) {
    try {
    // Create an image element to load the image
    const image = new Image();
    image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";  
    image.src = imageUrl;
    
    image.onload = async function() {
    // Create a canvas to draw the image onto
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    
    // Set canvas dimensions based on image size
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;
    
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
    
    canvas.toBlob(async function(blob) {
    if (!blob) {
    console.error("Error creating image Blob");
    return;
    }
    
    const imageFile = new File([blob], "image.jpg", { type: "image/jpeg" });
    
    if (navigator.share) {
    await navigator.share({
    text: description,  
    files: [imageFile]   
    });
    
    console.log("Shared successfully!");
    
    await navigator.clipboard.writeText(description);
    console.log("Description copied to clipboard!");
    
    alert("Image shared and description copied to clipboard!");
    } else {
    alert("Web Share API is not supported on this browser.");
    }
    }, "image/jpeg");
    };
    } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error sharing content:", error);
    }
    }
    
    document.getElementById("shareBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
    const imageUrl = "<?php echo $imageUrl; ?>";  
    const description = "<?php echo $description; ?>";  
    shareImageAsCanvasAndCopyDescription(imageUrl, description);
    });
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>


The support for the navigator.share API just isn't there. Not much you, or we, can do about that.
